# Flutter webview iOS error "default webview implementation for targetPlatform.macOS but there isn't one"

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I am new to Flutter, I tried webview with flutter and it works well with Android

I was trying to check it for iOS and I got
[image]

I am using

webview_flutter: ^3.0.0

Here's my code for it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(ScreenerWebView());

class ScreenerWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Screener',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
            child: AppBar(
              // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
              title: SizedBox(
                height: kToolbarHeight,
              ),
            )),
        // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
        body: WebView(
          initialUrl: "https://www.google.com/",
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package does not support macOS target which is the reason why you see the error

when you're on package's pubdev have a look on the `flutter` badge under `Published x days ago`, most of the time it will tell you which platforms are supported, in case of [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) it's only android and ios
[image]

Comment: As of now isn't yet supported in windows either