# WebView on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When trying to run the below code, we got the error

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
    home: WebViewApp(),
   ),
 );
}

class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebViewApp> createState() => _WebViewAppState();
 }

class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
       title: const Text('Flutter WebView'),
     ),
      body: const WebView(
      initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

In `import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';`
we got the error:
**Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or try using a URI for a file that does exist.**

Comment: Did you install the library with pub, and put it in your pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: @PaxonKymissis Yes I was installed and now it's fixed the error. But when running 'flutter run' will get an error on the screen 'unsupported operation: trying to use default webview implementaion for TargetPlatform.macos but there isn't default.'

Comment: This was brought up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70906118/flutter-webview-ios-error-default-webview-implementation-for-targetplatform-mac) , and unfortunately, webviews are not yet supported on mac. If you have an iPhone (or android) on you at the moment, you can try plugging it in and setting it to the build target.

Comment: @PaxonKymissis Thank you a lot for your reply. Do you mean webviews working for ios and android simulators?

Comment: Yes @Sara, they work for iOS and android simulators.